# How can unit test method that used WebTarget call inside it?

Tags: junit

I am trying to Unit test the below method. It makes a WS call and response contains a String that I need to use elsewhere.

```
   

     String[] getPathFromWS(WebTarget target) throws RuntimeException, IOException {
    
          
    
            Response response = target.request().header(AUTHORIZATION, getAuthorizationToken()).get();
    
            if (response.getStatus() != Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
                //do something
}
           //create responseArray from WS
            return responseArray;
        }
```

The JUnit test is below. I am trying to pass a mock WebTarget and use to generate required response.

```
    @Before
        public void setUp() {
            chemistryLicenseManager = new ChemistryLicenseManager(configMock);
        }
    
     @Test
        public void getPathFromWS_success() throws IOException {
    
            WebTarget webTargetMock = Mockito.mock(WebTarget.class);
            Builder builderMock = Mockito.mock(Builder.class);
            Response responseMock = Mockito.mock(Response.class);
    
            when(webTargetMock.request()).thenReturn(builderMock);
            when(builderMock.header(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(builderMock);
            when(builderMock.get()).thenReturn(responseMock);
    
            String jsonResponse = "{ \"" + "someKey" + "\": \"dummy paths\" }";
    
            when(responseMock.getStatus()).thenReturn(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode());
            when(responseMock.readEntity(String.class)).thenReturn(jsonResponse);
    
            String[] result = chemistryLicenseManager.getLicensePathFromWS(webTargetMock);
    
            //assertions here
        }
```

At present I am getting null pointer on line:
`Response response = target.request().header(AUTHORIZATION, getAuthorizationToken()).get();`
even if I am mocking the WebTarget. Can someone point out if I am missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution was pretty simple and possibly elusive because the error log did not have sufficient details.

```
when(builderMock.header(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(builderMock);
```

has a anyString() as second parameter but the actual method needs an object. So the below works :

```
when(builderMock.header(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(builderMock);
```

This also works on older versions:

```
when(builderMock.header(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyObject())).thenReturn(builderMock);
```